# Second argument of Code.compile_quoted/2 in Elixir

Tags: elixir

What is the meaning of the second argument in this Elixir function?

```
Code.compile_quoted(quoted, file \\ "nofile")
```

I tried to use it like this,

```
q = quote do
  defmodule A do
    def hello, do: IO.puts "hello from A"
  end
end
Code.compile_quoted(q, "Elixir.A.beam")
```

but the file `Elixir.A.beam` was not created.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly the internal feature for the compiler to build environment for back-reporting. It has nothing to do with beams, it’s the associated file name to spit it out to the user when needed.

```rb
q = quote do
  defmodule A do
    def hello do
      IO.puts "hello from A (" <> __ENV__.file <> ")"
    end
  end
end
Code.compile_quoted(q, "my_file.ex")
A.hello

#⇒ hello from A (my_file.ex)
#                ⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑
```

When [invoked by compiler internally](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.5.3/lib/elixir/src/elixir_compiler.erl#L27), it passes real file names there.

Comment: Thank you. The documentation says nothing about this.

Comment: This is because you are not supposed to run this method at all.

Comment: Well if something is publicly documented, and nothing says against using it, it is expected that people will use it.

Comment: Well, yes, to some extent. I mean, `Code.compile_quoted/1`, while is still considered a code smell, might be used as a last resort in some cases. If you are writing your own DSL compiler, you might need this function and that’s why it’s exposed. The latter means you won’t rely on docs in any case and will go examine the code. The code answers this question. If you don’t go to examine code, you presumably should not use this function :)

Comment: The documentation says: "A `file` can be
  given as second argument which will be used for reporting warnings
  and errors." What is missing?

Comment: @JoséValim hexdocs points to [`v1.5.3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.5.3/lib/elixir/lib/code.ex#L475), this sentence was added later.

Comment: I used `Code.compile_quoted/2` with the full umbrella file path `apps/myapp/lib/myapp/my_file.ex` to be able to recompile and reload the module. The use case is: a text file contains a DSL, is parsed with leex and yecc, produces Elixir code in RAM and in a source file (dumped for examination). By providing a file path I am able to change the source code manually in the produced file and recompile/reload it, just for debugging.